# how do i update my jtable after i add or delete my item

Tags: java, mysql, swing, oop

Im currently developing a database project. my jtextfield, addbutton, editbutton and the jtable was originally on one jframe. but when i made a addbutton to open another jframe and place the items to be added there, it works but it does not update my jtable, my jtable only updates after i make another action like editing or adding another item, what should be the problem here? here are the example of my edit button. btw i need it to be inserted and updated into my mysql

```
    if(editID.getText() != null)
    {
        String UpdateQuery = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        Connection con = main.getConnection();

        try{


            UpdateQuery = "UPDATE mydatabase SET name = ?, price = ?"
            + ", quantity = ? WHERE id = ?";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(UpdateQuery);

            ps.setString(1, editName.getText());
            ps.setString(2, editPrice.getText());
            ps.setString(3, editQuantity.getText());
            ps.setString(4, editID.getText());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            main.getProductList();
            main.Show_Products_In_JTable();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product Updated");

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }

    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "One Or More Fields Are Empty Or Wrong");
    }
```

so here is the two methods that i used to edit the table... but it seems incomplete, like i need a method in the main to simultaneously refresh my jtable. my brain are really exploding right now with this problem. cause i cant see any problem why moving my edit method from another jframe could affect my program.

```
public ArrayList<Database1> getProductList()
{
        ArrayList<Database1> productList  = new ArrayList<Database1>();
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM mydatabase";

        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;

    try {

        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        Database1 mydatabase;

        while(rs.next())
        {
            mydatabase = new Database1(rs.getString("id"),rs.getString("name"),rs.getInt("price"),rs.getInt("quantity"));
            productList.add(mydatabase);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(mainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return productList; 

}


public void Show_Products_In_JTable()
{
    ArrayList<Database1> list = getProductList();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)itemTable.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    Object[] row = new Object[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        row[0] = list.get(i).getId();
        row[1] = list.get(i).getName();
        row[2] = list.get(i).getQuantity();
        row[3] = list.get(i).getPrice();

        model.addRow(row);

    }
    itemTable.setModel(model);
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Comment: I think you should update your JTable by retrieving what you add recently on your database.

Comment: The table updates in response you make to the table model. If you've updated a value in the database, you will need to either duplicate that change in the table model and/or reload the value from the database and update the row in the model. It really has very little to do with your database and more to do with how you `TableModel` is managed

Comment: It "should" be possible to have all modifications (add/edit/delete) performed directly through the `TableModel`, which would then reflect those changes in the database, but that's a lot of design questions that need to be answered, to which we don't have the information we'd need to fully explore the possible options

Comment: `but when i made a addbutton to open another jframe and place the items to be added there, it works but it does not update my jtable` - why not? What is the difference if the table is in the same frame or another window? Either way you need a reference to the TableModel. So you need to pass a reference to the child window when you create the windowl Then your Add button can just update the model. Also, the child window should be a JDialog, not a frame.

Comment: Probably in your add button, add another method to refresh the table? @MadProgrammer is right, it's how you handle the table.

Comment: i edited my question and placed my other methods that i used. those two methods should be the one who places and updates the items on the jtable. the problems is they does not update my jtable after they added it. im really new to programming so im very sorry if i could not catch up what you guys are saying

Comment: i really need a refresh button or a method to refresh my table which is my problem right now. i tried a lot of methods from stack and youtube since i cant really fix it, but it seems i cannot find my solution yet